# Passing in arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line

How could I do something like this? I'm making a Sockets program that connects one program with another program via a port number. I want to pass in a command of `-p` that stands for port and then have a number after it to designate the port number. Example: `-p 9013` for Port 9013.

Here is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i, portNumber;

    for (i = 1; i < (argc - 1); i++) {
        if (strcmp("-p", argv[i]) == 0) {
            // add whatever comes after -p and declare portNumber as that integer
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue how I can maybe start this?

Comment: Did a search come up with nothing? I would think you are not the first person to want to use command line args.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html

Comment: What exactly is the question? You seem on the right track.

Comment: Well, basically, how can I take those four or whatever numbers after -p and set those numbers as portNumber (integer)?

Comment: `portNumber = atoi(argv[i+1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strcmp("-p", argv[i]) == 0) {
    portNumber = atoi(argv[i+1]) // Might want to check argv[i+1] exists in case the last command line parameter is "-p"
}
```